# While loop is not running properly

Tags: python, while-loop

I am trying to run a while loop in python. I can get most of it to function correctly but parts of the code are not working correctly and I have been trying different methods to solve it but I can't get it to do exactly what I want.

I am trying to write a program that which repeatedly reads numbers until the user enters “done”. Once “done” is entered, print out the total, count, and average of the numbers. If the user enters anything other than a number, detect their mistake using try and except and print an error message and skip to the next number

Here is my code:

```
total=0
number=None
count=0
while True:
    num=raw_input('Enter a number: ')
    print 'Enter a number',num
    for intervar in num:
        count=count+1
    if num=='done':
        break 
    else:
        try:
            number=int(num)
            if number is int: 
                continue
        except:
            print 'bad data' 
total=total+number
print 'Enter a number:',number
print 'Total is',total
print 'Count is',count
```

When I enter 3,4,5 The output from this code is:

```
Enter a number 3
Enter a number 4
Enter a number 5
Enter a number nine 
bad data
Enter a number done
Enter a number: 5
Total is 5
Count is 12
```

The code should read

```
Enter a number 3
Enter a number 4
Enter a number 5
Enter a number bad data
Enter a number done
Total is 12
Count is 3
```

Comment: you arent setting your total except for one time. total is outside of the for loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is your code rearranged a bit:

```
total=0
count=0
while True:
    num=raw_input('Enter a whole number: ')
    try:
        # just try to convert it
        number=int(num)
        # success -> accumulate
        total += number
        count += 1
    except ValueError:
        # if it isn't an integer, maybe they're done
        if num.lower() == 'done':
            break
        else:
            print 'bad data'
print 'Total is',total
print 'Count is',count
```

And here is an alternative

```
# keep all the numbers in a list for use later
numbers = list()
while True:
    num=raw_input('Enter a whole number: ')
    try:
        # just try to convert it
        numbers.append(int(num))
    except ValueError:
        # if it isn't an integer, maybe they're done
        if num.lower() == 'done':
            break
        else:
            print 'bad data'

print 'Total is', sum(numbers)
print 'Count is', len(numbers)
```

Answer (score 3):

You've got at least three remaining problems, here

**Problem 1**

```
for intervar in num:
    count=count+1
```

At this point `num` is a string and you are iterating over the characters in that string, incrementing `count`. The for loop is essentially equal to

```
count += len(num)
```

Do you want to count all inputs or only the correctly entered numbers?

**Problem 2**

The indentation of

```
total=total+number
```

is wrong. It must be inside the while loop. Also, use `+=` when adding to a variable.

**Problem 3**

The `is` operator compares the object identities of two objects. In this case, the comparison is true, iff `number` is the *class* `int`

```
if number is int: 
    continue
```

What you want is:

```
if isinstance(number, int):
    [...]
```

However, that is redundant, since after `number = int(num)` `number` is *always* an `int`.

Answer (score 2):

Use a list to track the numbers, perform calculations at the end of the input session.

```
numbers = []
while True:
    input = raw_input('Enter a whole number: ')
    try:
        numbers.append(int(input))
    except ValueError:
        if input is not None and input.lower() == 'done':
            break
        else:
            print 'Invalid input.'

length = len(numbers)
total = sum(numbers)
average = total/count

print 'Total is', total
print 'Count is', length
print 'Average is', average
```

Answer (score 1):

what you want to do is fix your increment for the total count

```
total=0
number=None
count=0
while True:
    input = raw_input('Enter a whole number: ')
    try:
        number=int(input)
        total += number
    except:
        if input.lower() == 'done':
            break
        else:
            print 'bad data'
            continue

    count += 1

print 'Total is',total
print 'Count is',count
print 'Average is', total/count
```

notice I changed your variable name from num to input since its not always a number... also your check for the type of number was incorrect so I changed that too.. you only want to increment when its a number so I put that in the try... also your count i changed to not loop over all of the characters inputted but rather just count 1 for each time they enter something

---

an even better way would be to write a number check function

```
total=0
number=None
count=0

def check_int(str):
    if str[0] in ('-', '+'):
        return str[1:].isdigit()
    return str.isdigit()

while True:
    input = raw_input('Enter a whole number: ')
    if check_int(input):
        total += int(input)
        count += 1
    elif input.lower() == 'done':
        break
    else:
        print 'bad data'
        continue

print 'Total is',total
print 'Count is',count
print 'Average is', total/count
```

the benefit of this drops the need for a try/except which has considerable overhead

Comment: That doesn't work either. `number` (or `input`) is initially `None`, which isn't an `int`. So the `elif` is always `False`.

Answer (score -1):

here is the code that prints your expected output.
you had an indentation error and too many prints.

```
total  = 0
number = None
count  = 0
while True:
    num = raw_input('Enter a number: ')
    if num == 'done':
        break
    else:
        try:
            number = int(num)
            if number is int:
                continue
        except:
            print 'bad data'
    count += 1
    total += number

print 'Total is',total
average = float(total)/float(count)
print 'average for %s is %s'%(count, average)
```